# perspective correction, texture interpolation opengl

Tags: math, opengl, graphics, textures, perspective

1)  In opengl, in texture mapping, when you specify texture coordinates for two different vertices,for a point in between are texture coordinates interpolated, or/and are the rgb values at the specified texture coordinates interpolated?

2) Also, could someone post/link to a full example (with actual coordinates) of texture coordinate interpolation with perspective correction- with world vertices associated with texture coordinates, transformed to clip coordinates, and then interpolated to find other texture coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by part 1. How do you omit texture or colour on a vertex?

Comment: oh yea good point, editing question

Answer (score 3):

In all 3D rendering where texture mapping is involved, texture coordinates are interpolated, and not just the colours of the texture at those points.

I read through the Wikipedia entry on texture mapping, and I think it is a good introduction.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping

After some more searching, this link seems to have working java code illustrating the concepts you are after.

http://tech-lib.net/books/GetTopic2?bookName=Developing%20Games%20in%20Java&topicTitle=A%20Simple%20Texture-Mapper

I was unsure if you were after glsl examples, or something else, so I just went for the broadest applicable answer.

Comment: Thanks. Wikipedia says: "Perspective correct mapping interpolates after dividing by depth z". What if depth z is 0? What ratios does opengl use to interpolate? I am aware light calculations use ratios between two vertices at the pixel level, not world ratios correct? These links are good, and i'm still looking for a full example with real coordinates, including texture, outside of code.

Comment: The z coordinate talked about in the links are the z coordinates af being transformed to screen/clip space, and is the distance from that coordinate to the eye. Because the near clipping plane is always > 0, all z coordinates will also always be > 0.

Comment: The magic of perspective (nonlinear) interpolation in opengl shaders comes from the fourth coordinate, W. (As in position.xyzw.) Default "no-op" value is w= 1.0.

The Z coordinate is thrown away (or clipped -1 to +1 against). But xyz are all divided by W on their way to screen space.

So, interpolating linearly on W, then dividing by it, gives perspective, straight lines remain straight, &c.